# How to fix spacemacs importmagic and/or epc not found?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I use spacemacs config to open a python file.

emacs: 25.3.1
spacemacs: 0.300.0
platform: osx

I add python layer in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`,
besides I use miniconda to control my python envs with `(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "~/miniconda3/envs")` in `dotspacemacs/user-init`.

Then I run into this problem(copy from *Messages*) when I open a python file:

```
Importmagic and/or epc not found. importmagic.el will not be working.
```

Tried to solve this situation from discussion at [spacemacs#10145](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10145)
by add

```
(require 'pyvenv)
(pyvenv-activate DIRECTORY)
```

into my `dotspacemacs/user-config` but with no lucky.

Hope someone could give me some advice, thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you

```
pip3 install importmagic epc
```

in the python environment you're working in?

Comment: Strangely `apt install python3-importmagic elpa-epc` did not work.

Comment: @JPVentura Install it in your *virtual python environment* e.g. `pipenv install importmagic epc`

Answer (score 4):

`pip install importmagic epc` should work.

If not, check this variable: `python-shell-interpreter`, this is the python which need to install the packages.

Comment: i had to combine this answer with the accepted one to produce the command `ipython -m pip install importmagic epc`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running spacemacs and lsp-mode for python.  It turned out that I hadn't activated lsp on that directory / project and it wasn't running.

Once the lsp layer was running again, then the importmagic and epc errors went away.